# Compiled shader not working?

Tags: c++, shaders, directx, hlsl

I did a simple pixel shader that makes the texture monochrome, and it works perfectly when it is precompiled, but not when compiled (returns E_FAIL).
The effect was compiled using fxc.exe with these arguments: fxc /T ps_2_0 /Fo BasicHLSL.fxc BasicHLSL.hlsl

Here's the code

```
ID3DXEffect* monochromeShader = nullptr;

void initEffects(GameWindow& w)
{
    long errorID =
    D3DXCreateEffectFromFile
    (
        w.getD3DDevice(),
        "data/shaders/BasicHLSL.fxc\0",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        D3DXFX_NOT_CLONEABLE,
        NULL,
        &monochromeShader,
        NULL
    );

    std::cout << std::hex << errorID;

    if (monochromeShader == nullptr)
        showErrorMsg(std::to_string(errorID).c_str());
}
```

And here's my shader before compiling with fxc.exe:

```
// Pixel shader input structure
struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Position   : POSITION;
    float2 Texture    : TEXCOORD0;
};

// Pixel shader output structure
struct PS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Color   : COLOR0;
};

// Global variables
sampler2D Tex0;

PS_OUTPUT ps_main( in PS_INPUT In )
{
    // Output pixel
    PS_OUTPUT Out;

    Out.Color = tex2D(Tex0, In.Texture);
    float4 f4 = Out.Color * float4(0.299f, 0.587f, 0.114f, 1.0f);
    float f = f4.r + f4.g + f4.b;
    Out.Color.rgb = f;

    return Out;
}

// Effect technique
technique tech_main
{
    pass P0
    {
        // shaders
        VertexShader = NULL;
        PixelShader  = compile ps_2_a ps_main();
    }  
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you compiled the shader with the `ps_2_0` profile which means it's a *pixel shader* binary blob and not an "Effect" binary blob. It does not contain "techniques" or "passes".

You can use that binary blob to create a pixel shader directly without using the optional "Effects" system:

Here's a simple 'binary blob loader':

```
inline std::vector<uint8_t> ReadData(const wchar_t* name)
{
    std::ifstream inFile(name, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    if (!inFile)
        throw std::exception("ReadData");

    std::streampos len = inFile.tellg();
    if (!inFile)
        throw std::exception("ReadData");

    std::vector<uint8_t> blob;
    blob.resize(size_t(len));

    inFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    if (!inFile)
        throw std::exception("ReadData");

    inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(blob.data()), len);
    if (!inFile)
        throw std::exception("ReadData");

    inFile.close();

    return blob;
}
```

Then you create the shader:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> blob = ReadData(L"data/shaders/BasicHLSL.fxc");

HRESULT errorID = w.getD3DDevice()->CreatePixelShader(blob.data(), &monochromeShader);
```

If you want to use the Effects system, you need to use the `fx_2_0` profile:

```
fxc /T fx_2_0 /Fo BasicHLSL.fxc BasicHLSL.hlsl
```

See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/)

> Please note that Direct3D 9 is legacy, `D3DX` is deprecated along with the DirectX SDK itself, the `fx` profiles are deprecated in the modern versions of the HLSL compiler, the use of the "Effects" system generally is discouraged. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx), [Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/), and [Effects for Direct3D 11 Update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/10/23/effects-for-direct3d-11-update/)

Answer (score 0):

**[D3DXCreateEffectFromFile Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172768(v=vs.85).aspx)**

The last parameter is to a LPD3DXBUFFER that holds compilation errors, which you can use to determine exactly why this compile (and any future similar compiles you may do) failed.

```
LPD3DXBUFFER errBuff = NULL;

D3DXCreateEffectFromFile (..., &errBuff);

if (errBuff)
{
    // contains the error string
    char *errStr = (char *) errBuff->GetBufferPointer ();

    // contains the size (in bytes)
    int errSize = errBuff->GetBufferSize ();

    // clean up
    errBuff->Release ();
}
```

Comment: Now the error i'm getting is the following: ID3XEffectCompiler: There were no techniques ID3XEffectCompiler: Compilation failed